# Overriding window = onload

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

I have a page within wordpress that I want to password protect via a user role plugin. Everything works fine on straight forward pages but I have a page with `window.onload = function() {` that completely overrides the password function.

I want the page to load immediately after it's checked to see if the user is logged in or not.

Update:

I'm using [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members/) and I just have the function:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
(function() { 

window.onload = function() { 
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);
...
} } )
</script>
```

Which then loads on this div:

```
<div id="map" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
```

Comment: Are you checking for the password in Javascript in an `onload`? If so, that is very trivial to bypass.

Comment: if your password can be overridden via javascript being on the page then all a user has to do is turn off javascript to view the page no?

Comment: @AndrewMarshall No it's checking for the password via a plugin which is unrelated to the onload stuff.

Comment: There's not enough detail here. Code?

Comment: Rob: so you do *not* want to load the map if the user is not authorized, right? So you need to make sure that script tag and the map div goes in the part of the page that's controlled by the authorization plugin(so you shouldn't see them rendered to the page at all via "View Source" if not authorized).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of assigning it directly to the `onload` property add it as an event listener

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener

You'll need to use `attachEvent` for IE versions < 9.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536343(v=vs.85).aspx

If you're using a framework such as jQuery or Prototype this can be abstracted out so you don't need to worry about different browsers.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `addEventListener` or `attachEvent` to load multiple functions. If you want to use `window.onload = ..`, use the code in the last `else` block at the function below:

```
function addEvent(name, func) {
    if (window.addEventListener) {
        window.addEventListener(name, func, true);
    } else if(window.attachEvent) {
        window.attachEvent('on' + name, func);
    } else {
        var other_func = typeof window['on'+name] == "function" ? window['on'+name] : function(){};
        window['on' + name] = function(ev){
            func(ev);
            other_func(ev);
        }
    }
}

addEvent('load', function(){
   //Load function 
});
```