# onload and onunload JavaScript events with GA time tracker

Tags: javascript

```
<html>  
<head>  
<title>Latency Tracking Demo</title>  
</head>  
<body>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/scripts/time-tracker.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">  
var timeTracker = new TimeTracker();  
var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker('UA-1735986-1');   
</script>  
<input type="button" value="Start Timer" onclick="timeTracker._recordStartTime();"/>  
<input type="button" value="Stop Timer" onclick="timeTracker._recordEndTime();"/>  
<input type="button" value="Track!" onclick="timeTracker._track(pageTracker, undefined, 'Manual Test');"/>  
</body>  
</html>
```

I am trying to apply this concept on onload JavaScript event as Start Time and onunload as Stop time , like

```
  onload="timeTracker._recordStartTime();"
    onunload="timeTracker._recordEndTime(); timeTracker._track(pageTracker, 'Category','Action');"
```

But have not get it work ..and even not error was thrown

any idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function loadIt(){
  timeTracker._recordStartTime();
}

function unLoadIt(){
  timeTracker._recordEndTime(); 
  timeTracker._track(pageTracker, 'Category','Action');
}
```

Then (I use this function)

```
function addOnloadEvent(func){
    var oldOnload = window.onload;
    if(typeof window.onload != 'function') {
        window.onload = func;
    } else {
        window.onload = function() {
            if(oldOnload) {
                oldOnload();
            }
            func();
        }
    }
}

addOnloadEvent(loadIt);
//window.onunload = unLoadIt  //Do the same for unload
```

It takes the function name, without () or quotes

> Instead of assigning it directly to the onload property add it as an event listener

Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7954904/643500)